# how can i generate ebay api token automatic

Tags: php, api, token, ebay-api

how to generate token ebay api automatic with php

i have try to make it with this :

```
<?php
$devID = '518664de-29b9-46e6-ba1b-63b3e4a93f18'; 
$appID = 'dropship-dropship-PRD-25b778b89-8248278e';
$certID = 'PRD-5b778b89c307-a516-45d6-b096-a310';
$devToken = "v^1.1#i^1#p^3#f^0#r^1#I^3#t^Ul4xMF8xOkQ1NzIxMUQ2NEFBRENGMTA2ODk0OEI1QkZGQjA3QkEyXzJfMSNFXjI2MA==";
$authCode = 'v%5E1.1%23i%5E1%23f%5E0%23r%5E1%23I%5E3%23p%5E3%23t%5EUl41Xzg6RDk3MEFCQjNDMDRENEE3NzIzOEE4NzExQUM1QTVEMDNfMF8xI0VeMjYw';
$ruName = "dropshipping-dropship-dropsh-okvoihtlt";
$scope = "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing.readonly https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory.readonly https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account.readonly https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment.readonly https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.analytics.readonly https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.finances https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.payment.dispute https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.readonly https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.notification.subscription https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.notification.subscription.readonly";
$serverUrl = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';
$authToken = "";
$refreshToken = "";

$link = "https://api.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
$codeAuth = base64_encode($appID.':'.$certID);
$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: Basic '.$codeAuth
));
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLHEADER_SEPARATE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&amp;code=".urlencode($authCode)."&amp;redirect_uri=".urlencode($ruName)."&amp;scope=".urlencode($scope));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if($json != null)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";
    // echo $authToken = $json["access_token"];
    // echo "<br><br>";
    // echo $refreshToken = $json["refresh_token"];
}else {
    echo 'no data in this';
}
```

and i show this =>

(
[error] => invalid_request
[error_description] => request is missing a required parameter or malformed.
)

so help me what is my problem and how can i fix it . thanks

Comment: Are these live credentials?

Comment: have tried with `&` instead of `&amp;` in PostFields? that does not need to be `urlencoded`
Beside this, never, never, never show live credentials!!

Comment: A feedback would be appreciated...